# Discord.js ${message} not working when I try to print

Tags: discord.js

I am working on a discord bot and I want to print the messages that I received. Console should printl this when I write "hello" on my server:
hello
But it looks like this:
${message}
In tutorial I watch, it works but mine doesn't

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('${message}'); 
});
```

Comment: Please can you provide us with more of your code. Where have you defined client?

Comment: message is a class object, you want to print message.content right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
console.log(message.content)
// Or this, if you really want to wrap this in a string
console.log(`${message.content}`)
```

Your code won't work for multiple reasons :

First of all, you can't call a var like this: `'${message}'` returns a string, not the var. The `${}` syntax is only supported in backticks.

Then, `message` won't return your message's content, however `message.content` will.